# Extjs Ext.get method basics

Tags: javascript, extjs, spket

I am using Ext.get to get an element. I am using Eclipse and Spket. In Spket editor I see the get method is red in color. Also there is no auto complete support for the variable I declared.

```
var exp = Ext.get('id'),
exp.
```

is this a correct behavior? Why there is no auto complete for exp variable ? am I using correct Ext method ? What would be the best practice?
I think this might be more of a Spket question. any pointer would be helpful.

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: `Ext.get()` retrieves Ext.Element objects which encapsulate DOM elements, Ext.get will return value only when element is rendered on dom,at runtime `exp` can have reference to it.

Comment: Use IntelliJ IDEA - much better support for JS.